# How to get the internalDate in Gmail API?

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I am using Gmail API and am getting the variables in Javascript. I can access the `Date` but not the `internalDate`.

```
  var inDate = getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'internalDate');
  console.log(inDate);
```

it does not log anything; the string is empty. But when I log the `Date`, it logs the date like this: "Sun, 15 Jul 2018 21:41:56 +0000"

```
  var Date = getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Date');
  console.log(Date);
```

Now, how do I get the `internalDate` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of accessing internalDate from `message.payload.headers`, try to access the internalDate from `message.internalDate`

Eg:

```
var internalDateVal = message.internalDate;
```

Comment: I just figured this out. And you gave the right answer. Thank you!